# Acceder a los mensajes de msg.property desde el BackingBean de JSF

Tags: java, jsf

Me gustaria saber como puedo acceder a los mensajes que tengo creados en el archivo mensajes.properties desde una clase BackingBean de JSF.

La idea es crear una función en el BackingBean que dependiendo del valor de una variable, la función devuelva un mensaje u otro. De tal forma que en la vista (xhtml) pueda llamar a esta función del BackingBean y esta me devuelva el mensaje correspondiente de entre todos los que hay en el mesajes.porperties. La idea seria algo asi:

mensajes.properties)

```
Mensaje1=bueno  
Mensaje2=regular  
Mensaje3=malo
```

ControladorBB)

```
private int var = 0;

public String obtenerMensaje(){  
   if(var == 0){  
       //return Mensaje1  
   }  
   if(var == 1){  
       //return Mensaje2  
   }  
}
```

Vista (xhtml)

```
<h:OutputText value="#{ControladorBB.obtenerMensaje()}" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una opción seria utilizar un Properties

```java
//Buscas el archivo
InputStream input = BackingBean.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("mensajes.properties")

//Declaras el Properties
Properties prop = new Properties();

//Le asignas el archivo
prop.load(input);

//Buscas la propiedad
public String obtenerMensaje(){  
   if(var == 0){  
       //return Mensaje1  
       return prop.getProperty("Mensaje1");
   }  
   if(var == 1){  
       //return Mensaje2  
       return prop.getProperty("Mensaje2");
   }  
}
```

Comment: Esa solución funciona. Pero en el caso de que el archivo mensajes.properties se encuentre en el mismo proyecto que el BB. Si en mi caso el archivo properties se encuentra en un proyecto padre y el BB en un proyecto hijo del padre. ¿Como puedo hacer para que el BB encuentre el archivo mensajes.properties del proyecto padre? Porque ahora mismo el input me devuelve null, ya que creo que no puede encontrar la ruta.

Comment: Probaste cargando el classloader de ese proyecto padre, en vez de usar una clase de tu proyecto usa una del jar del que deseas sacar las propiedades y deberia cargarte su classloader y obtener los recursos dentro del mismo